# Windows Authentication with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ldap, windows-authentication

I want to achieve an automatic login in my webapp if the logged user is inside the company domain. To be more specific, I need to check if the logged windows user is inside the domain and, if so, retrieve the email by the LDAP server and if not, a login page will be shown.
To do so I'm considering to use the Tomcat "Windows Authentication" but I'm wondering **why** the tomcat server has to act like a domain controller as stated in this [how to guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have not configured tomcat for windows authentication.
But from the documentation that you links to it look like it could be an misunderstanding.

> **Domain Controller**
>
> These steps assume that the server has already been configured to act as a domain controller.

This I think refers to the server that will act as the Domain Controller. If tomcat runs on server A and server B is the domain controller, then the steps assume that server B is configured.